# Visual Studio 2013, installation stuck every time at the same point

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio

I'm trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 ultimate version on my laptop, but every time the installation stuck at the same point like in the image below:

[image]

My laptop specification:

- Windows 8.1 x64 ultimate.
- 6 gb RAM
- i7 processor

I also disabled the antivirus and not using any other program while install, but without any luck maybe for more than 5 times. I hope if there is a solution.

Comment: Have you had any other versions of visual studio installed? I had a problem like this with difrent versions conflicting each other.

Comment: No, i don't have any other versions.

Comment: Have you tried starting the install with administrator rights?

Comment: yes, i did but still the problem

Comment: By "stuck" do you mean that the installer freezes, i.e. the loading bar and the little moving dots stop for a long period of time?

Comment: no, the installer keep running but like for ever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a lot of search, i found that the installer is the problem even if you download from original source, for me i did theses steps:

1. I extracted the original ISO ( 
   not mounting).
2. When installing the application if its stuck for more than 15 min in the same place don't close, just restart the computer.
3. After the computer starts work, click to install again it will continue from the last point it stuck on.

i did it for 2 times then its works perfect.

i hope this can help.

Comment: Had this same problem but for me using Task Manager to end-task on the installer and then running it again worked, I didn't have to reboot.

Comment: Not restarting makes the installer report "Another Installation is in progress. Please wait to retry again..."

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, that is the web installer? have you tried downloading it? I installed from the web installer, but you might be installing some features that I didn't. I guess I was also using express.

If you can pick and choose from the various additional features, try installing only VS, then look into adding in the extra features post-install.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing from an ISO file, then your ISO file may be corrupted, then try to install from web installer. Or of you are using web-installer, then try to install from visual studio ultimate ISO image file.